# training a nn with f1 as loss on keras doesn't work?

Tags: neural-networks, keras

I have no problem to train my neural network with categorical_crossentropy as loss but when I do the same with f1, it just doesn't progress :

Epoch 1/9
1029/1029 [==============================] - 4384s 4s/step - loss: 0.9470 - f1: 0.9470

Epoch 3/9
1029/1029 [==============================] - 1401s 1s/step - loss: 0.9413 - f1: 0.9413 - val_loss: 0.9938 - val_f1: 0.9938

Epoch 7/9
1029/1029 [==============================] - 1405s 1s/step - loss: 0.9270 - f1: 0.9270 - val_loss: 0.9932 - val_f1: 0.9932

Here's my implementation of f1:
def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.

```
    Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.

    Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
    how many relevant items are selected.
    """
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    """Precision metric.

    Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.

    Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
    how many selected items are relevant.
    """
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision
precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

Do you have an idea of what might be the problem ?

Comment: do you always get constant loss (without slight change)?

Comment: Constant I don't know but it's always very low. Why ?

Comment: if it constant than it means that, probably, weights don't get updated and it's possible when gradients are always 0. I believe that f1-score should produce 0 gradient

Answer (score 0):

F1 score is non-differentiable, thus cannot be used as a loss function.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: Is it possible to round the curve artificially around the sharp turns to make the function differentiable ? Can we replace the 'round' in the f1 function by something else ?